# Can anyone translate this Rails code to PHP?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, cakephp

I learned ruby on rails before php and need a quick answer.

I'm trying to do something like this in CakePHP.

```
@foo = Foo.find(:all)
@some_foos = @foo.select { |i| i.status == 4 }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly translates to:

```
$foo = Foo::find($all);
$some_foos = $foo->select(function($i) {
    return $i->status == 4;
});
```

In other words, it's calling the static find method on the Foo ActiveRecord and assigns the result. Then it selects from those results those records which satisfy the anonymous function and assigns those as well.

Try this for [CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html) (untested):

```
$foo = $this->Foo->find('all');
$some_foos = array_filter($foo, function($i) {
    return $i['Foo']['status'] != 4;
});
```

If you dont need all the Foos, you want to fetch the relevant records instead:

```
$some_foos = $this->Product->findAllByStatus('4');
```

or via raw SQL

```
$some_foos = $this->Foo->query("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE status = 4;");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need to know what this would be in CakePHP.  $this->$foo->select() doesn't work.

Comment: @user647345 CakePHP is inspired by RoR but it's not a 1:1 port of RoR.

Comment: I understand, but there must be a way to do this in Cake...  This seems so simple, but I can't find how and I'm tearing my hair out.

Comment: @user well, have you looked at their manual? updated answer.